# How can I export Super Meat Boy replays?

Tags: super-meat-boy

I've just finished Super Meat Boy 6-5 (after 3 hours, I think I won't be able to use my hands anymore), and I was wondering something. How are people posting SMB runs on the internet exporting their replays? I've found the replays, in .rpl form, but I don't know how to convert them to a readable format.

The answer may (and will probably) be "video capturing software", but most of the videos had no watermark, so I was curious if there is another way.

Comment: thanks for the edit, non-native speaker here, thought my english was good :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replays you saw were most likely captured using FRAPS, it's the most commonly used screen capture software. The pro version has no watermark.

Comment: That's what I thought, just thought I'd ask just in case :)